# Mocha - How can I set a variable with a before block?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

My example has

```
let resort30 = new Resort('Alta');
```

at the top of the file and then uses it within the the test case, i.e.

```
let alta = new Visit(resort30, '03/01/2000'); // Note this is before any describe
```

That works.  However if I create a `before` or `beforeEach` within the `describe` and before all the `it`s with:

```
before(function () {
  let resort30 = new Resort('Alta');
});
```

and comment out the original declaration, then `resort30` isn't recognized with

```
 ReferenceError: resort30 is not defined                                                                                                  
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/ski_resorts_using_befores.spec.js:52:26)
```

How can I get it to work when I move that variable into the `before` or `beforeEach` so all `it`s can use it ?

I don't want it at the top, I want it to be scoped to the describe as I plan more describes in this file.  Even with 1 describe , I want to be able to use `before` and beforeEach` for variables and objects i wanna create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is visible only in the scope it has been declared or from inner scopes. That's why it's not recognized in another scope. To have some kind of a global variable but scoped to the `describe()` block you need to declare it at the top of the block and initialize in the `before()` or `beforeEach()` block:

```
describe('Test suite', () => {

    let resort30 = null;

    before(() => {
        resort30 = new Resort('Alta');
    });

    it('should pass', () => {
        console.log(resort30);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh, just need to define it, not actually set it.  i can do a bunch on 1 line too.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't able to see resort30 because if you declare it inside a function, it's scoped only to that function.

```
let resort30; // declare it at the top level scope of the file

before(function () {
    resort30 = new Resort('Alta'); // modify the value here
});
```